# Typescript create array with loop dynamically

Tags: typescript, angular

Am creating a mock class, for generate example data for my Angular2 TypeScript project. Am still a beginner with programming, and struggle with the informatie that is available about TypeScript. My question:

I want to create 100 items and save them in an array. The 100 items will be generated dynamically. The static way i use is very simple, but how do I can do this dynamicly? I made a begin with some iteration code, but how can I best replace the console.log code, and let the output of the iteration be as the static data. I need some examples

**mock-names.ts** (Static)

```
export var NAMES: Name[] = [
    {"id": 01, "name": "Tony"},
    {"id": 02, "name": "Jake"}
]
```

**mock-names-dynamically.ts** (Dynamically)

```
export var NAMES = [];

for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

**name.ts** (Name Class file)

```
export class Name {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Comment: Where the names values will come from? Also, it seems that you have a class called Name, could post this class here?

Comment: The class name.ts is used. I added the class to my post.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

All you have to do is use the push function of the array in Javascript.

```
var NAMES = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    let newName = {
       id:i.toString(),
       name:"Tony"
    };
    NAMES.push(newName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand what your code is doing. I will try this!

Comment: I works but not completely for me.
The 100 items are created with only the name, and without the Id. I need to figure that out. But am now at the right direction, thanks.

Comment: Based on my code snippet, the id of each object should be a string representation of the i value. Please double check your code.

Comment: This was stupid The problem was in my class, sorry. But again thanks!

Answer (score 9):

ES6 Way:

```
 const getData = () => Array.from(new Array(100), (val, index) => ({
       id:index.toString(),
       name:"Tony"
    };);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of dynamic initialization, if you are not sure about the size of the array-

```
let list:Array<{_id:string,name:string}> = Array()
```

Then simply push values using a loop

```
list.push({_id:'it001',name:'Sam'})
```