# How to create an array of different lenght each time it's called

Tags: javascript, angular, materialize

The case I'm working on right now, I make a HTTP GET request and I get an array of id's and data (from a json), which so far I've been able to successfully print on screen (like this `<li *ngFor="#date of dates">{{date.date2}}</li>` ). I want that array to be used in another component, component2:

I have another component that shows a small box that displays several buttons. I got it from materializecss and currently shows statically 5 buttons. I can change it by hand but I would like to do it so it adjusts to however many answers I got from the previous components. So if I get 3 id's, I want it to show 3 options.

This is the array `items = ['a', 2, 3, 4, 5];`

Which is then used in a template like this:

```
 <div flex="50" *ngFor="#item of items">
                    <md-checkbox [checked]="exists(item, selected)" (click)="toggle(item, selected)">
                      {{ item }} <span *ngIf="exists(item, selected)">selected</span>
                    </md-checkbox>
                  </div>
```

In other languages this is pretty basic but I'm not sure if it is done in angular 2, in html with the help of another ngFor, or how. Honestly I lack the vocabulary to search how this is done, so I'm sorry if it's way too basic.

This [Typescript create array with loop dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36556349/6028947)  is the closer I've got but either it doesn't work for my case or I don't get it.

Edit: pseudo-code for what I'd like to do:

```
void method(Integer items){
int n = items.length;
int[] array = new int[n];
}
```

Being items the "object" or data or array that I want to dynamically use in the second component.

The second component is basically a classic subscriber, practically the same as this

```
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  heroes: Hero[];
  mode = 'Observable';
  constructor (private heroService: HeroService) {}
  ngOnInit() { this.getHeroes(); }
  getHeroes() {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
                     .subscribe(
                       heroes => this.heroes = heroes,
                       error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
  addHero (name: string) {
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.heroService.addHero(name)
                     .subscribe(
                       hero  => this.heroes.push(hero),
                       error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
}
```

But with different data.

The structure of the app is... kind of big/messy as of right now, due to my lack of experience, but it would go like this:

```
src/sidenav.ts //@Component with imports of other components (including httpC) and all the relevant template, which I'll post below
src/service.ts //@Injectable
 |src/httpC.ts //@Component


<form>
  <calendar></calendar>
  <HTTPgetRequest></HTTPgetRequest>
  <checkS></checkS>
  <button></button>

</form>
```

And so the idea is to use what I get from the request, into the checkS selector (which are some ticking boxes, so for however long the array from the request is, I want to have as many checkboxes)

Comment: Can you provide some more details about this second component and the structure of your app? Is it a child of the first component (if so using `@Input` would definitely be an option)?

Comment: I just did, hope it's properly explained (I tried hard!), if you have a moment and don't mind @JRulle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have three elements (parent component, child component and a service). The parent element retrieves the list (array) from the service and passes the list down into the child component via an `@Input`.

**Parent:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child-component';
import { MyService } from './my-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [MyService],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>List</h2>
      <child [list]="parent_list"></child>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  parent_list: string[] = [];

  constructor(private _myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parent_list = this._myService.getList();
  }
}
```

Child:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let item of list">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() list: string[];
}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  getList() {
    // some function that returns your list
    return ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3'];
  }
}
```

[**Here is a working example that is a bit more flushed out**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQtQYksEgJUOaJuJI8C6?p=preview).
[*Here is an egghead.io video on @Inputs*](https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-passing-data-to-components-with-input)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will look into this asap, I got until I tried to use input and everything stopped working so this is going to help me a great deal, been two hours already stuck with trying to use Input, so thanks a lot!!

Comment: Would this still be possible to do if the component using the service and the one using the list were different? It has to be, but as I am currently trying to figure that now I wanted to ask. Also, thanks again!

Comment: I dont really understand your question... in my example the components are different (one is nested inside the other - parent-child relationship). The two components could be siblings (sitting next to each other in the structure sharing a common parent). the common parent would need to provide the service so both components would be interacting with the same instance of the service.